# Getting "ARCHIVE FAILED" error while doing archive process using command "xcodebuild archive \"

Tags: ios, ssh, archive, github-actions

I have one iOS project in Swift language and I have to create archive and .ipa using command on terminal.

I am using Github actions for uploading iOS build on test flight.
I am following all instruction which mentioned in this link:

https://zach.codes/ios-builds-using-github-actions-without-fastlane/#install-gpg

When I am hitting this command on iMac system's terminal:

```
xcodebuild archive \
            -workspace GitHubActions.xcworkspace \
            -scheme GitHubActions \              
            -sdk iphoneos12.4 \            
            -configuration Release \       
            -archivePath $PWD/build/GitHubActions.xcarchive \
            IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
            PROVISIONING_PROFILE="<UUID>" \
            CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="<Code_Sign_IDENTITY>"
```

I am getting success response:

```
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
```

But When I am connecting my iMac using this command:

```
ssh <system_username>@192.168.1.100
```

I am connecting successfully then I have reached to project folders using 'cd' command.

And then when I am hitting the same command:

```
xcodebuild archive \
                -workspace GitHubActions.xcworkspace \
                -scheme GitHubActions \              
                -sdk iphoneos12.4 \            
                -configuration Release \       
                -archivePath $PWD/build/GitHubActions.xcarchive \
                IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
                PROVISIONING_PROFILE="<UUID>" \
                CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="<Code_Sign_IDENTITY>"
```

But when I am using this command on another system then I am getting this error:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/webcubator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GitHubActions-djymswinwihmdobtcnvllpcfgvht/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GitHubActions/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/GitHubActions.build/Release-iphoneos/GitHubActions.build/Script-678E7AE3D9F6AC7BF3ABDA96.sh
(1 failure)
```

What exactly I am doing wrong. Not able to understand. Whey this error is showing when accessing iMac from another system.

Answer (score 2):

After search a lot I finally found the solution of issue where I was not able to submit using remote connection from other system.

keychain handles your keys and certificates (used by code sign to sign your build ) is not usable out of the box for the remote user. Its needs to be unlocked first !!!

To know about the available keychains on your system just type in on your terminal :

```
security list-keychains
```

You should see something like :

```
"/Users/'YOURUSER'/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

And you guessed it right there, you have to unlock the keychain of your user ! Juste run this :

```
security unlock-keychain -p 'USER_PASSWORD' 'PATH_TO_USER_KEYCHAIN'
```